# MongoDB comparar cadenas sin importar su orden

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

No tengo mucha experiencia con mongo, y necesito hacer una búsqueda en un input, y que me encuentre, por ejemplo: ( cafe dolca ) ó ( dolca cafe ) y me traiga el mismo producto a seleccionar

estoy usando aggregate, ya que mi función es aún más compleja y necesito de los resultados que me traiga, pasarlos a varios lookups

````
            [
                {
                    $match: { // ! encontrar dentro de User mediante or por lo que paso por parametro
                        tipo: tipo,
                        $or: [
                            { 'name': regex },
                            { 'brand': regex }
                        ]
                    }
                }, ``` 

regex sería lo que escribe el usuario en el input.
````

Answer (score 0):

Logré solucionarlo del siguiente modo:

```
                {
                $search:
                {
                    search: {
                        path: "name", query: regex
                    }
                },
            },
```

, El tema es que no se como hacer un $or, ya que tambien necesito buscar en otro path, y aún no se como solucionar eso.

Answer (score 0):

Logre solucionar la pregunta anterior de este modo:

```
{
                $search: {
                    "compound": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "text": {
                                    "path": "name",
                                    "query": regex
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "text": {
                                    "query": regex,
                                    "path": "brand"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
```

Ahora necesito hacer un regex para que no me encuentre las palabras completas, y no se como hacerlo, pero se los dejo aca por si a alguien le hace falta

Comment: Todo esto fue gracias también ah que creé un Atlas Search, en la web de mongodb, ahi es donde tengo alojada la base de datos, no sabría como hacerlo en un vps normal